# Install Software with dpkg

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, deb

I installed [SME](http://storagemadeeasy.com/) dpkg -i sme.deb, it installed it but I could not start it.

However when I started the software center it told me that something was broken and it needed fixing, so I allowed it and after it was finished, SME started.

So what I want to know should i install deb files with dpkg -i commend or should I use other commend ???

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dpkg` tells you what went wrong if you read its output.

However if you like GUI apps, I would recommend GDebi to install `deb` files, although if something goes wrong it will recommend you to open a terminal and do a `sudo apt-get install -f`.

To install GDebi: `sudo apt-get install gdebi`. Then for every `deb` file you have, right click and select `Open With` -> `GDebi`.

And a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
sudo dpkg -i <package_name.deb>
```

is the standard way of installing `.deb` files on ubuntu. However, this won't install any dependencies for you, so this would mean if you want to install a package that requires some other package you will have to install the required package yourself first and then install the package you want to.

`apt` is a software that will handle this concern for you and handle all required dependencies. However, this will not install packages that are not available in the repositories or as [ppa's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them).

So, yes if you have `.deb` file, you should be using `dpkg` to install package but use `apt` whenever you have to install packages that are available in the repositories.